# Org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap but no jar version mismatch

Tags: java, spring

I am getting j`ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap` even when I include s`pring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE`. I cant see any version mismatch.

```
05-Jun-2017 14:49:47.955 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1271)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:972)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:945)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 54 more
```

mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.3.174:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:provided
[INFO] +- apache-log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.2:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.8.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compil
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.amos.utils:core-logging-utils:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.amos.utils:core-http-utils:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.8:provided
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:jar:0.8.1:test
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:asm:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:0.8.1:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss:jboss-common-core:jar:2.2.9.GA:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-spi:jar:2.0.5.GA:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.directory.api:api-all:jar:1.0.0-M16:compile
[INFO] |  +- xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.mina:mina-core:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:17.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3:compile
```